# What means "ever-fleeting"?

Tags: meaning

"Our existence is based solely on the *ever-fleeting* present"

What does it mean?

Comment: For English language learners, see https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression refers to the continually (ever) disappearing (fleeting) nature of the "present", or the "now". The idea is that the present is something that vanishes as soon as it exists, changing into the past before you can get a grip on it. Another way of saying this would be to refer to the "ephemeral" nature of the present.